# Identity Generation with MySql and H2 for local testing

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, h2

I'm new here, so I hope it's not a stupid question.

I am using a MySQL DB and am trying to use an H2 DB alongside for local tests. I am running into problems when persisting new objects, i.e., objects that do not yet have an Id. It works fine on the running system using MySQL, but currently the local tests in H2 fail with the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1306)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:871)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2936)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:818)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:865)
    ... 33 more
```

I use the following persistence annotations in the corresponding Java class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "myclass" )
public class MyClassDbo {

    private MyClassId id;

    @Id
    @Column( nullable = false )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Type( type=MyClassIdType.FQ_CLASS_NAME )
    public MyClassId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    ...
}
```

The persistence configuration looks like this. For production:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url"  value="jdbc:mysql://@my.db.host@/@my.db.schema@"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username"  value="@my.db.user@"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"  value="@my.db.password@"/>
```

For local tests:

```
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"  value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:db1;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=true;INIT=create schema IF NOT EXISTS generic" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"  value="sa"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"  value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"  value="create-drop"/>
```

The MySQL DB is setup with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE MYCLASS 
    (    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ... )
```

The H2 DB is setup using a testdata.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <MYCLASS ID="1" .../>
</dataset>
```

with the following code

```
JdbcDatabaseTester databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester( "org.h2.Driver", "jdbc:h2:mem:db1;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=true;INIT=create schema IF NOT EXISTS generic;", "sa", "" );
    File file = new File( "testdata.xml" );
    databaseTester.setDataSet( new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build( file ) );
    databaseTester.setSetUpOperation( DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT );
    databaseTester.setTearDownOperation( DatabaseOperation.NONE );
    return databaseTester;
```

and when I look into the H2 DB, everything looks correct to me, the ID column is marked to be the primary key and has a default value which generates an ID.

I am using the following versions:

- Java 7
- MySQL Connector 5.1.40
- Hibernate 4.1.9
- H2 1.3.173
- DB Unit 2.4.9

I have not found a way to make MySQL and H2 work together here. I have tried different GenerationTypes and the only idea I have right now is to create my own IdentityGenerator which depending on the setup either manually creates an Id for the H2 DB or behaves like the standard IdentityGenerator for MySQL. However, with this I deploy code dedicated for testing into the running system which I would like to avoid.

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions! And please tell me if I forgot any important information.

Comment: Try using `IDENTITY` rather than `AUTO` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I have tried both AUTO and IDENTITY without success.

Comment: Can you verify that the column is actually AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL?  Not what your script is saying, but actually what MySQL tells you.

Comment: mysql> desc myclass;

`+--------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+`
`| Field                          | Type         | Null | Key | Default      | Extra          |`
`+--------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+`
`| ID                             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL         | auto_increment |`